# Is there any way to cancel an active file upload using meteor-slingshot?

Tags: meteor, meteor-slingshot

I want to provide users with the ability to cancel an existing file upload, is there any workaround to allow this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with version 0.6.1 there is...

If you upload your file like this:

```
var uploader = new Slingshot.Upload("myFileUploads");

uploader.send(document.getElementById('input').files[0]);
```

Then you can abort it with:

```
uploader.xhr.abort();
```